# AngularJS does not include a template

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I've bootstrapped Angular onto my Rails project using [this guide](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2014/9/25/how-to-set-up-angular-with-rails)

And in the console I get a "exampleApp running", So Angular is working. Next step was to try and include a template into the index file.

I've added this to the index.html.erb

```
<div ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>
```

But it doesn't include the template.

This is my structure

- app

  - assets

    - javascripts

      - angular-app

        - app.js.coffee
        - templates

This is the content of my app.js.coffee file

```
@app = angular.module('app', [
  # additional dependencies here, such as restangular
  'templates'
])

# for compatibility with Rails CSRF protection

@app.config([
  '$httpProvider', ($httpProvider)->
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
])

@app.run(->
  console.log 'angular app running'
)
```

But I'm not seeing the 'angular app running' message in the console, so I think this file isn't doing anything.

Any ideas on what the problem is?

// edit.

This was my index.html

```
<div ng-app='app.exampleApp' ng-controller='ExampleCtrl'>
  <p>Value from ExampleCtrl:</p>
  <p>{{ exampleValue }}</p>
</div>

<div ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>
```

And I realized that I wasn't loading the template in the ng-app so obviously it wasn't working.

I moved the include in the ng-app and now I'm getting a 404 error. So at least its trying to include the file.

// edit 2

By changing the path to the template to `<div ng-include="'assets/angular-app/templates/header.html'"></div>` it's including the file.

Comment: Open console, what do you see, 404 for template request?

Comment: There's no feedback from the ng-include command in the console. In the HTML it shows '<div ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>' which is just empty.

Like I said it looks like the problem is with the app.js.coffe file which routes the templates because if I remove that file nothing changes in the project.

Comment: template path should be relative to your index page. What is index page path?

Comment: right, is templates folder in same folder where your index file is?

Comment: No the template folder is inside the angular-app folder. And the app.js.coffe file (which includes the template path) is also inside the angular-app folder.

Comment: What is your index.html path?

Comment: app > views > example > index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84688/discussion-between-dhavalcengg-and-peter-boomsma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `ngInclude` is outside of the Angular app so it's never rendered and processed.

It should be:

```
<div ng-app='app.exampleApp' ng-controller='ExampleCtrl'>
  <p>Value from ExampleCtrl:</p>
  <p>{{ exampleValue }}</p>

  <div ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>
</div>
```

or you can put `ng-app='app.exampleApp'` on some topmost common parent container like `body` or `html`.

Comment: I allready saw that (see my edit), the problem now is the path. I'm getting a 404 error in the log.

Comment: Check resources tab and note that pass app.js was loaded from. If it's `localhost:3000/some/path/app.js` then you also need to use something like this for ngInclude `src="'some/path/tempalates/header.html'"`.

Comment: You're right.`<div ng-include="'assets/angular-app/templates/header.html'"></div>` does load the template. But I would rather type `templates/header.html` then the path everytime. Is there a way to set a template path?

Comment: You need to set base path in index.html. Add to head section `<base href="assets/angular-app">`. Then all relative paths in the app like image src, link href will resolve relative to the base.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to type whole long path you can use html5 base tag

```
<base href="assets/angular-app" target="_blank">
```

This way you are changing base resource path to /assets/angular-app.

So no need to type it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ng-include src="'templates/header.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<ng-include src="'./templates/header.html'"> </ng-include>
```

and check your path :)

Comment: It's trying to load the template file now, because I was trying to load the file outside the ng-app div so rails just output the html. But I'm getting a 404 message in the console log. 'GET http://localhost:3000/templates/header.html 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: Try it like this : <ng-include src="'./templates/header.html'"> </ng-include>